# Finding out why ListBox loses selection

Tags: wpf

When I switch back to random window and switch back, one of the listboxes loses its selection. SelectionChanged event is fired and I can not find why.

Is there a method to debug this?

Comment: Are you manipulating with value using the XAML (Data Binding) or code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth placing a `Window.Activated` or `Application.Activated` method to help breakpoint the cause.

The change could be occuring as you switch back so breaking into code at that point may help you debug the problem